# Disable scrolling down breaks menu links in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I'm using fullPage.js, especifically onLeave function to disable scrolling down in my website. This would be okay but I'm having issues using the menu because I just can scroll in one direction.

This is my code:

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){ 
  if (direction == 'up') { 
    return false;              
  } else {
    return true;
  };
}
```

So, if I am on the number 3 section, and want go to section number 4, the page will be blocked. How could I handle an exception for my menu?

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for but a suggestion. You can write this code in just one line `return direction !== 'up'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using [$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'down');](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setallowscrollingboolean-directions)
 ?

From [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setallowscrollingboolean-directions):

> Adds or remove the possibility of scrolling through sections by **using the mouse wheel/trackpad or touch gestures** (which is active by default). Note this won't disable the keyboard scrolling. You would need to use setKeyboardScrolling for it.

That won't disable your links.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterRender: fuction(){
        $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'down')
    }
});
```

If you also want to disable the keyboard, then you need to use [`setKeyboardScrolling`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setkeyboardscrollingboolean-directions) as well.

Comment: This works perfectly, but I have just one more question, when I was using onLeave, I was making an alert appear when I scrolled down using $(".Alert").css("visibility", "visible"); I tried to do it with the new functions but didn't work, there's any method for making those alerts appears?

Comment: You should figure out why its not working. You are missing something very probably.